# Read, calculate and write data on a huge table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, html-table, profiling

I have a huge table (up to 10 000 rows). I have to go through every row, calculate some data and write it on two cells in every row.

I do something similar to:

```
$('#table tbody').find('tr:visible').each(function() {
        var tr = $(this);
        var a = tr.children('.cell3').text();
        tr.children('.cell4').html(xxx.calculate(parseFloat(tr.children('.cell1').text()), a, b ));
        tr.children('.cell5').html(xxx.calculate(parseFloat(tr.children('.cell2').text()), a, b));
    });
```

and I see, profiling, this is where most of the time is spent during calculation.

- I tried to cache all the children ( var tds tr.children('.cell1, .cell2, .cell3') ) and then use tds.get() for retrieve values.
- I tried to use innerHTML js native method

But I had no significant improvements.

Do you have any advice or see something poor in my code? Is it the best I can obtain?

PS: Cells could be in a different order, so I have to access them through class name

Comment: What does `xxx.calculate` do?

Comment: xxx.calculate just do some operations with cells value, based on other calculate values (that b), I can't say something more, because it's a private project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10000 rows are a lot to traverse, for some gain, try to use native method as much as possible.

couple of quick suggestions, don't know if it will result in huge gain but should be relatively fast:

**1. Use plain for loop, with cached length**

10000 rows to loop are best test case to check performance difference between $.each vs plain for loop.

```
var items = $('#table tbody').find('tr:visible');

var length = items.length;
for(var i = 0; i< length; i++)
{

  var tr = $(items[i]); 
  var a = tr.children('.cell3').text();
        tr.children('.cell4').html(xxx.calculate(parseFloat(tr.children('.cell1').text()), a, b ));
        tr.children('.cell5').html(xxx.calculate(parseFloat(tr.children('.cell2').text()), a, b));
}
```

**2. Use find() instead of children(), check [jsperf here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-children-td)**

```
var items = $('#table tbody').find('tr:visible');

var length = items.length;
for(var i = 0; i< length; i++)
{

  var tr = $(items[i]); 
  var a = tr.find('.cell3').text();
        tr.find('.cell4').html(xxx.calculate(parseFloat(tr.find('.cell1').text()), a, b ));
        tr.find('.cell5').html(xxx.calculate(parseFloat(tr.find('.cell2').text()), a, b));
}
```